# Why am I getting a TokenMismatchException with Laravel and JQuery Sortable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

**Update**
*I've changed the question slightly based on answers I've been given*

I'm trying to save an order of rows, after the user manipulates the table via JQuery's Sortable Library.

```
<div class="nametag-layout">
        <table class="table table-striped pagin-table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Duration</td>
                    <td>Intent</td>
                    <td>Module</td>
                    <td>Outputs</td>
                    <td>Inputs</td>
                    <td>Logistics</td>              
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($mods as $key => $value)
                <tr class="table-tr draggable" data-id="{!!$value->id!!}">
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_duration }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_intent }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_module }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_output }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_input }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $value->mod_logistics }}</td>
                    <td>                            
                        <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" style="margin:auto; display:block;" href="{{ URL::to('mods/' . $value->id . '/edit') }}">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

After the table is manipulated, a js function takes the new order of the rows and passes it via a call.

```
$( "tbody" ).sortable({ 
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        var ids = new Array();
                        $('tr', this).each(function () {
                            ids.push($(this).data('id'));
                        });
                        $.get(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids});
                    }
            });
```

And a sort function in my controllers takes those values and parses them, then saves it to the DB so the new order is saved.

```
public function sort() 
{
        $ids = request()->get('ids');
        if ($ids != null) {
            foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
                $value = Mod::find($id);
                $value->sort = $i;
                $value->save();
            }
        } 
}
```

Every time I refresh the page, it doesn't save the order which I've moved the rows into. Checking chrome inspector and checking the XHR filter shows that every time I move a row, the sort function fires off, but every time it does fire off, a 'TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken' error occurs. I'm assuming either the js function isn't actually passing the values across to the controller, or I've messed up the call.

I've also added '/sort' to the $except parameter in 'VerifyCsrfToken.php', to temporarily fix the csrf issue I'm getting.

My route looks like this:

*Route::get('/sort',array('as'=>'strawdog.sort','uses'=>'StrawdogController@sort'));*

When I've done all this, the ajax call is sending the data to the controller, after checking using the XHR filter on chrome inspector, but whenever the rows are refreshed, it goes back to the original order of the rows instead of the manipulated order.

Basically, what am I doing wrong?

**Things I've tried:**

I've tried changing my js function to match the controller (post/get):

```
$.post(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids});

public function sort() 
{
        $ids = request()->post('ids');
...
```

Changing both to the 'get' parameter just causes it to call another function I've written. Changing both to the 'post' parameter just returns the 'TokenMismatchException' error again.

---

I've tried another option, where I've changed the js function to 'get':

```
$.get(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids});
```

and the function to get as well:

```
$ids = request()->get('ids');
```

and removed the function that conflicted with the get parameter. Then I've written a show function which handles to redirect to '/sort'.

```
public function show()
{
    return redirect('/sort');
}
```

Going back to the chrome inspector and checking the XHR filter shows that it is passing the values across, but the sort function returns a 'NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179' error.

For reference, my route looks like this:
  *Route::get('strawdog/sort',array('as'=>'strawdog.sort','uses'=>'StrawdogController@sort'));*

Comment: using `$.post()`  reading with `post` .. `$.get()` reading with `get` .. So use `$.get()` and `get('ids')` or `$.post()` and `post('ids')`

Comment: Changing to:   $.post(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids}); to match the controller just returns the same error. Changing my controller to $.get causes it to call another function instead of the sort one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your **VerifyCsrfToken.php** middleware

Do this (add any route you want to crsf exception)

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        '/sort'  // add the correct route here
    ];
}
```

Comment: I've added '/sort' to VerifyCsrfToken.php, and changed all the parameters to 'get' and it appears to pass fine, but it still doesn't save the order of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel framework has csrf protection.see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf.

You can add

```
var token = '{{csrf_token()}}';
$.post(window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "/sort", {ids: ids,_token:token});
```

in your ajax data or see the solution in Laravel docs

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to add it to my ajax data?

Comment: see the code after edited,And the code should be written in the blade files

Comment: I'm getting 'Use of undefined constant csrf_token - assumed 'csrf_token'

Comment: so sorry,it's a function `{{csrf_token()}}` not constant

Comment: I've added that to what I've got, and it doesn't throw any errors anymore, but it doesn't appear to save the row order to the database.

Comment: Do you write the save function?

Comment: It uses the save function that laravel provides.